# PHP String/Variable To Array And Check String/Variable Null

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I want create string to array. I have 4 variables:

```
    <?php 
      $name = "John";
      $address = "Moscow";
      $born_date = "13-11-1995";
      $color = "red"; 

      $join = $name.":".$address.":".$born_date.":".$color;
      $array = explode(':', $join);
      print_r ($array);
    ?>
```

This array result is:

```
Array ( [0] => John [1] => Moscow [2] => 1995-11-13 [3] => red )
```

When I change `$color` variable to `null` like `$color="";`

This result like this:

```
Array ( [0] => John [1] => Moscow [2] => 1995-11-13 [3] => )
```

I want `array` number 3 not to show. I want if all `$variable == NULL` / `$variable=="undefined"` / `$varable=""`

Show like this:

```
Array ( [0] => John [1] => Moscow  [2] => 1995-11-13)
```

The array shows only variable filled.

Comment: Use `array_filter($array);` or use `if` conditions. Or make your array using `if` conditions and `$array[] = $name;` etc...not sure you need to create a string just to `explode()` it to an array when you can just make an array.

Comment: See @DontPanic for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your requirements are, but it seems strange to create this array by joining the variables together and then exploding them. You could just add them directly to the array, and add the color conditionally:

```
$array = array($name, $address, $born_date);
if ($color) {
    $array[] = $color;
}
```

If you need all of the elements to be added conditionally, you can create an array containing all of them and then use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) as Rasclatt suggested to eliminate the empty ones.

```
$array = array($name, $address, $born_date, $color);
$array = array_filter($array);
```

If it is important that the keys remain sequential, you can use

```
$array = array_values(array_filter($array));
```

Comment: i try your code, and i change  $color="" and $born_date=""

Comment: this born_date always show, so i must create else if again ?

Comment: Do you mean that each of the elements should only be included in the array if they are not `null` and `!= ""`?

Comment: yes. if $born_date="" / $color="" / $name="" / address="" this resut array not show

Comment: if  $born_date and $color null > Array ( [0] => John [1] => Moscow  )

Comment: i try like this  > http://pastebin.com/i8Nvkasg  i fill $born_date="undefined"  i want $born_date not show in array, you know ?